# How to slice a sparse matrix in scala breeze?

Tags: scala, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I create a sparse matrix in scala breeze, ie using http://www.scalanlp.org/api/breeze/linalg/CSCMatrix.html.  Now I want to get a column slice from it.  How to do this?

Edit: there are some further requirements:

1. it is important to me that I can actually do something useful with the slice, eg multiply it by a float:

   X(::,n) * 3.
2. It's also important to me that the resulting structure/matrix/vector remains sparse.  Each column might have a dense dimension of several million, but in fact have only 600 entries or so.
3. I need to be able to use this to mutate the matrix, eg:

   X(::,0) = X(::,1)

Answer (score 3):

Slicing works the same as for DenseMatrix, which is discussed in the [Quickstart](https://github.com/dlwh/breeze/wiki/Quickstart).

```
val m1 = CSCMatrix((1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11, 12), (13, 14, 15, 16))
val m2 = m1(1 to 2, 1 to 2)
println(m2)
```

This prints:

```
6   7   
10  11
```

Comment: Interesting.  You're right.  So, if I want just one column I can do for example m1(0 to 2, 0 ).  I have to say I think it would be nice to be able to do m1(::,0) , but you have answered my question, so I will mark your reply as the answer.

Comment: Whoops, I mean m1(0 to 2, 0 to 0), which is not exactly as terse as I would like.

Comment: Hmmm, wait, there are two problems with this (three if one includes the non-concise syntax).  I cant multiply the slice by a number, eg `m1(0 to 2, 0 to 0 ) * 3.` does not work. And the type of the slice is no longer sparse.

Comment: And another problem: I can't use this to mutate the matrix, eg I cant do m1(0 to 2, 0 to 0) = m1(0 to 2,1 to 1)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own slicer method in the end.  Use like this:

```
val col = root.MatrixHelper.colSlice( sparseMatrix, columnIndex )
```

code:

```
// Copyright Hugh Perkins 2012
// You can use this under the terms of the Apache Public License 2.0
// http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

package root

import breeze.linalg._

object MatrixHelper {
   def colSlice( A: CSCMatrix[Double], colIndex: Int ) : SparseVector[Double] = {
      val size = A.rows
      val rowStartIndex = A.colPtrs(colIndex)
      val rowEndIndex = A.colPtrs(colIndex + 1) - 1
      val capacity = rowEndIndex - rowStartIndex + 1
      val result = SparseVector.zeros[Double](size)
      result.reserve(capacity)
      var i = 0
      while( i < capacity ) {
         val thisindex = rowStartIndex + i
         val row = A.rowIndices(thisindex)
         val value = A.data(thisindex)
         result(row) = value
         i += 1
      }
      result
   }
}
```

Comment: Thinking about it, this doesn't actually let me mutate the matrix, but it does at least result in a sparse vector, not a dense one, and I can multiply it and so on.

Comment: Marking this answer as accepted for now, since noone has provided anything better.

Comment: To the downvoter, please leave a comment explaining the downvote.